# Automate the Script whenever a new folder/file is added in directory in Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, automation, jupyter-notebook

I have multiple folders in a directory and each folder has multiple files. I have a code which checks for a specific file in each folder and does some data preprocessing and analysis if the specific file is present.
A snippet of it is given below.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import os

rootdir = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

df_list = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith("StudyParticipants") and file.endswith(".csv"):
            temp = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(subdir, file))
                           .....
                           ..... 
                          'some analysis'

Merged_df.to_excel(path + '\Processed Data Files\Study_Participants_Merged.xlsx')
```

Now, I want to **automate** this process. **I want this script to be executed whenever a new folder is added**. This is my first in exploring automation process and I ham stuck on this for quite a while without major progress.

I am using windows system and Jupyter notebook to create these dataframes and perform analysis.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote a script which you should only run once and it will work.
Please note:

1.) This solution does not take into account which folder was created. If this information is required I can rewrite the answer.

2.) This solution assumes folders won't be deleted from the main folder. If this isn't the case, I can rewrite the answer as well.

```
import time
import os


def DoSomething():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # go to folder of interest
    os.chdir('/home/somefolders/.../A1')
    # get current number of folders inside it
    N = len(os.listdir())
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)  # sleep for 5 secs
        if N != len(os.listdir()):
            print('New folder added! Doing something useful...')
            DoSomething()
            N = len(os.listdir())  # update N
```

Comment: Can I get some help with choosing folders which starts with 'RK22BB'. If new folder is added and it starts with 'RK22BB', only then the code has to be run.  I thought of inserting a for loop inside the while, but I thought it would take a big processing time. I am sure, there would be an efficient way.

Comment: Without giving it too much thought:
1.) Before the "while" loop, create a list of all folders. e.g. my_folders = os.listdir()
2.) if N != len(os.listdir()), it means a new folder was added.
3.) Find difference between my_folders and os.listdir(). e.g.:
difference = list(set(my_folders) - set(os.listdir()))

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way. You could also iterate through the entire list "os.listdir()" and look for your folder by comparing the elements of the list with the name of the folder that you're looking for.
I'm limited to 600 characters for my comment, hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at watchdog.

http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-create-a-watchdog-in-python-to-look-for-filesystem-changes/

you could also code a very simple watchdog service on your own.

1. list all files in the directory you want to observe
2. wait a time span you define, say every few seconds
3. make again a list of the filesystem
4. compare the two lists, take the difference of them
5. the resulting list from this difference are your filesystem changes

Best greetings